# The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found on the java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm newly at server development and have been started from easy tutorial by 
Lars Vogel.
[Servlet and JSP development with Eclipse WTP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) .

***Step by step*** accord this tutorial:

- installed Eclipse Java EE Kepler;
- installed tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 - `http://localhost:8080/` shows correct tomcat page;
- Setting up tomcat runtime environments into eclipse;
- added tomcat server to eclipse;
- create `DAO`;
- created the Servlet;
- run =>

And here I caught next prompt:

```
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:com.filecounter' did not find a matching property.
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5203 ms
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:45 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [171] milliseconds.
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2013 3:40:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2882 ms
```

Here is content of `tomcat/lib` folder:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/lib$ ls -lg
total 6132
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   15264 Jul  2 10:59 annotations-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   54142 Jul  2 10:59 catalina-ant.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  134215 Jul  2 10:59 catalina-ha.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art 1581311 Jul  2 10:59 catalina.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  257520 Jul  2 10:59 catalina-tribes.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art 1801636 Jul  2 10:59 ecj-4.2.2.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   46085 Jul  2 10:59 el-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  123241 Jul  2 10:59 jasper-el.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  599428 Jul  2 10:59 jasper.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   88690 Jul  2 10:59 jsp-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  177598 Jul  2 10:59 servlet-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art    6873 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-api.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  796527 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-coyote.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  235411 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-dbcp.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   77364 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-i18n-es.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   48693 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   51678 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art  124006 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-jdbc.jar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nazar_art   23201 Jul  2 10:59 tomcat-util.jar
```

[Here is content of catalina.2013-09-15.log](http://pastebin.com/vaB7jV19).

**Update:**

Here is tutorial:
[Installing Apache Tomcat Native on Linux Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.sheroz.com/installing-apache-tomcat-native-linux-ubuntu-1204)

**Update2:**

Here is content of Data Access Object:

```
public class FileDao {

  public int getCount() {
    int count = 0;
    // Load the file with the counter
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null ; 
    try {
      File f = new File("FileCounter.initial");
      if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        writer.println(0);
      }
      if (writer !=null){
        writer.close();
      }

      fileReader = new FileReader(f);
      bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
      String initial = bufferedReader.readLine();
      count = Integer.parseInt(initial);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      if (writer !=null){
        writer.close();
      }
    }
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
      try {
        bufferedReader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  public void save(int count) throws Exception {
    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    fileWriter = new FileWriter("FileCounter.initial");
    printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    printWriter.println(count);

    // Make sure to close the file
    if (printWriter != null) {
      printWriter.close();
    }
  }

}
```

And here Servlet code:

```
public class FileCounter extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  int count;
  private FileDao dao;

  public void init() throws ServletException {
    dao = new FileDao();
    try {
      count = dao.getCount();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      getServletContext().log("An exception occurred in FileCounter", e);
      throw new ServletException("An exception occurred in FileCounter"
          + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Set a cookie for the user, so that the counter does not increate
    // every time the user press refresh
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    // Set the session valid for 5 secs
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    if (session.isNew()) {
      count++;
    }
    out.println("This site has been accessed " + count + " times.");
  }

  public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
    try {
      dao.save(count);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

I haven't had `web.xml` yet.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: @A4L I tried this path `http://localhost:8080/com.filecounter/FileCounter` but it throws `HTTP Status 404 - /com.filecounter/FileCounter`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

The native lib is expected in one of the following locations

```
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
/usr/lib64
/lib64
/lib
/usr/lib
```

and not in

```
tomcat/lib
```

The files in `tomcat/lib` are all `jar` file and are added by tomcat to the `classpath` so that they are available to your application.

The native lib is needed by tomcat to perform better on the platform it is installed on and thus cannot be a `jar`, for linux it could be a `.so` file, for windows it could be a `.dll` file.

Just [download the native library for your platform](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) and place it in the one of the locations tomcat is expecting it to be.

Note that you are not required to have this lib for development/test purposes. Tomcat runs just fine without it.

> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 2882 ms

**EDIT**

The output you are getting is very normal, it's just some logging outputs from tomcat, the line right above indicates that the server correctly started and is ready for operating.

If you are troubling with running your servlet then after the `run on sever` command eclipse opens a browser window (embeded (default) or external, depends on your config). If nothing shows on the browser, then check the url bar of the browser to see whether your servlet was requested or not.

It should be something like that

```
http://localhost:8080/<your-context-name>/<your-servlet-name>
```

**EDIT 2**

Try to call your servlet using the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/com.filecounter/FileCounter
```

Also each web project has a web.xml, you can find it in your project under `WebContent\WEB-INF`.

It is better to configure your servlets there using `servlet-name` `servlet-class` and `url-mapping`. It could look like that:

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>File counter - My first servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>file_counter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.filecounter.FileCounter</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>file_counter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileFounter</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In eclipse dynamic web project the default context name is the same as your project name.

```
http://localhost:8080/<your-context-name>/FileCounter
```

will work too.

Comment: In my location exist last three paths. I misunderstood how to exactly download this libs? Here is link for tomcat 7 - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html

Comment: @nazar_art follow the instructions in this [page](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)

Comment: @nazar_art which error? If it is `The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path` then follow the steps in the tutorial you found or in the link from the apache tomcat site. Or do you have another error? (The only 'error' - it's actually just a warning - I see is about ARP!)

Comment: I followed this tutorial but maybe have missed smt coz this warning is showed again. I couldn't understand the end of this tutorial `Now I have compiled Tomcat Native library in /usr/local/apr/libtcnative-1.so.0.1.27 and symbolic link file /usr/local/apr/@libtcnative-1.so pointed to the library

5. Create or edit the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh file with following lines :
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/apr/lib'`

Comment: @nazar_art, please see my edit! also just ignore the warning about ARP if you are just starting up with servlets and tomcat.

Comment: Exactly it shows me this page into eclipse (http://localhost:8080/com.filecounter/) but shows `HTTP Status 404 - /com.filecounter/` too. At browser the same result.

Comment: @nazar_art I cannot access your `localhost`, you only can ;-) please update your question and post the content of your web.xml file and the code of your servlet.

Answer (score 12):

Regarding the original question asked in the title ...

- `sudo apt-get install libtcnative-1`
- or if you are on RHEL Linux `yum install tomcat-native`

The documentation states you need http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/

- `sudo apt-get install libapr1.0-dev libssl-dev`
- or RHEL `yum install apr-devel openssl-devel`