# Tomcat 7 server won't start within eclipse with error `Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m`

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

While executing my simple hello world program I am getting a the Tomcat Server error as

> “Starting Tomcat Server v7.0 at localhost (2) has encountered a problem”

I am using jdk7 nd spring 3.1.0 and I have not yet introduced hibernate or maven. Can Anyone help me fix the error. The Console output is as follows:

```
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\lib;D:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8\bin;D:\Softwares\Eclipse Dump\EclipseForSpring;;.
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1082 ms
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:32 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [203] milliseconds.
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorld'
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:34 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorld': initialization started
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:34 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloWorld-servlet': startup date [Thu Aug 21 10:15:34 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:34 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/HelloWorld-servlet.xml]
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4258426: defining beans [helloWorldController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWorld': initialization completed in 936 ms
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 21, 2014 10:15:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4138 ms
```

Comment: which operating system and IDE with version are you using ?

Comment: Can you provide full error message? Please Click On detail.

Comment: Win 7, Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: @TAsk : Can you help me upload an image???

Comment: You can provide image link in your question.

Comment: The Detail says `Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost (2) was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.`

Comment: my server.xml says `<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>`

Comment: As mentioned in the help, I made a image link, but it won't appear, not even in the preview.

Comment: May be because I was giving the image link of my own harddisk, How and where do i need to upload the image to give a link to the question ?????

Answer (score 0):

Its seems this problem doesn't have anything to do with spring, hibernate or maven. As it is saying
             its expecting an `native library` which it cant find. You can find that native library in [Tomcat Native](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/)
             and store it in position as tomcat expect it

This [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812762/the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-pat) discuss the same problem as yours.

As you are using windows i recommend you to use `tomcat installer` to avoid unnecessary problems.

**The message you are getting is normal. You can ignore it as i think its not creating any issue**
But still you want or solve this you need to compile the source package that comes as `Tomcat Native` 
Which i haven't tried yet. It is said in tomcat site `Use MS Visual Studio to open the workspace of the APR sources and build the library (libapr).` and further instruction also given.

Comment: I used an installer only to install the tomcat 7. Still if so, can you guide me a link as to where to find the missing Tomcat library. I tried But got a C++ Code from the link `Tomcat Native`. Looking forward for some good help

Comment: i have provided the link with my answer **Tomcat Native** http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/ and also read this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812762/the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-pat

Comment: Sorry to say Saif, but the Post is for Linux/Ubuntu and I am using Win7. I have downloaded the dll, but don't know what to do with it and where to place it???

Answer (score 0):

You can change the eclipse tomcat server configuration. Open the server view, double click on you server to open server configuration. Then click to activate "Publish module contents to separate XML files". Finally, restart your server, the message must disappear.

This time page will come without any issues.[image]

Comment: Did the same... No Luck... Error remains the same... Is there anything else we can add to it???

Comment: try by adding a system property to the launch configuration of the tomcat server in eclipse.

 -Djava.library.path=[tomcat_home]\bin

as well tcnative-1.dll 64/32 bit download and place it in bin folder.  hope it will work

Comment: `tcnative-1.dll` already exists in `[tomcat-home]\bin` directory...... How and which system property do i add to the launch configuration. Please be a little more clear...

Comment: Open eclipse and your project and then right click on it and go to Run As ->Run Configurations then a window will appear. Scroll the list box to your left and double click on Java Application. One you do this, another window will appear and you will see a Tab named Arguments. Click on Arguments. After you have clicked on Arguments you will see the VM Arguments lable. In the VM Arguments type this -Djava.library.path=c:\dev\tomcat\bin and close out and the warning should not come up when you run you project.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, this was quite detailed and clear... It worked well I Guess... But still the same original error occurs... May be this was not enough... Something else too needs to be taken care of...  Please maintain your support.