# j2ee i am not able to launch my project

Tags: java, tomcat

I have the following message when deploying my application in Tomcat:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\bag\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BagShopinning\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

But it seems you are packaging a `servlet-api.jar` in your WAR file which conflict with the one already provided by your servlet container. You can try to not package the `servlet-api.jar` in your WAR file.

Comment: when m trying to run  my project it gives me 404 error, and on console it gives error like jar not loaded

Comment: It seems you are deploying through Eclipse, you can try to right click on your project, select "Properties", then "Deployment Assembly" and remove the "servlet-api.jar" entry. Then redeploy.

Comment: did the same, but now m getting error like :  Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Comment: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:           now m getting this error::  and also the SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812762/the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-pat

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the servlet-api jar file from, WebRoot -> WEB-INF -> lib folder.
and you can put this jar file into another folder, outside WEB-INF -> lib folder.

It will work.
but you need to put this jar file some where in your project because at compile time we need servlet-api jar and at runtime our tomcat will take care of it.

Best luck.