# Can deploy war in tomcat outside Eclipse but cant in Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant, war

I have an ant project in eclipse IDE. Ant build creates a war inside dist folder. I copy that war to Tomcat's webapps folder and successfully deploy it. Now I add Tomcat to the eclipse and try to deploy the war in here and it ignores the war file. It does not give any exception bu does nothing useful as well. Below is the complete Tomcat log -

> Jun 23, 2015 12:12:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
>   optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;%PATH%;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin;D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
>   Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;D:\eclipse;;. Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ServiceManager' did
>   not find a matching property. Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 408 ms Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Jun 23, 2015 12:12:07 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 Jun 23, 2015 12:12:09 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Jun 23, 2015 12:12:09 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Jun 23, 2015 12:12:09 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   1869 ms

It is a Dynamic Web Module project. Am I missing some configuration while setting up the Tomcat in Eclipse ?

Comment: try to deploy whole project in tomcat. It should work fine. I believe tomcat in eclipse accepts a web project.

Comment: didn't get you. how do I deploy the whole project? And how to make it a web project ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful for you, [someone else happened the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812762/the-apr-based-apache-tomcat-native-library-was-not-found-on-the-java-library-pat).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing the runtimes configuration
PROJECT>PROPERTIES >PROJECTS FACETS >new runtimes
[image]